# Weird Python print behaviour on mac

Tags: python

It's my first time using Python on mac, I tried to print this simple code which runs perfectly fine on my friends Windows os laptop, but on my mac it runs differently. Here's how it looks on my screen vs friends screen.

My screen : https://ibb.co/gRwwRJq
Friends screen : https://ibb.co/W31g1dg

any suggestions on how i can fix that ?

Comment: You may be using different versions of Python. Instead of commas, use `+` to concatenate in print statements, or it'll print a `tuple`

Answer (score 1):

One person is using `python 2.x` and the other is using `python 3.x`.

[This](https://ibb.co/gRwwRJq) person is using `python 2.x` and [this](https://ibb.co/W31g1dg) person is using `python 3.x`

See the difference between the results using the below links.

*Python 2.7* - https://repl.it/repls/AstonishingOrnateDeclaration

*Python 3.7* - https://repl.it/repls/AnotherBelovedSystemsanalysis

To make it work the same with `python 2.x` you can use this [repl](https://repl.it/repls/AbandonedEssentialSeptagon) or this [repl](https://repl.it/repls/NeatAmazingFiles).

Comment: What's wrong with the newest version ? shouldn't both work the same ?

Comment: the reason is what JammyDodger said in the comments

Comment: _shouldn't both work the same?_ If they were the same, they wouldn't be different versions.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, `print` is a function. In Python 2 (unless you use `from __future__ import print_function`), it is a statement. This has subtle implications for how parentheses are treated.

The print statement takes a comma-separated list of expressions, and prints each one separated by a single space. `print(...)` is a `print` statement with a single parenthesized expression as an argument, so `print("a", "b")` prints a single tuple, not two separate strings:

```
# Comma separates expressions in the statement
>>> print "a", "b"
a b
# Comma builds a tuple, which is the single expression
>>> print("a", "b")
('a', 'b')
```

The `print` function is like any other function; the parentheses are part of the function call syntax, and do not affect the intepretation of the individual arguments. To print a tuple, you would need *additional* parentheses so that the comma separating `a` and `b` is treated as the tuple constructor, not the argument separator.

```
# Comma separates arguments in the function call's argument list
>>> print("a", "b")
a b
# Comma builds a tuple, which is passed as the loan argument
>>> print(("a", "b"))
('a', 'b')
```